# 13.04 Asus Ux31e

Tags: sound, 13.04, asus

I just upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04. Now it appears the sound is not working.

In the sound settings, the only output available it dummy output.

Any ideas how to get this working? Installing drivers again etc?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Not much to go on here.  Can you provide more details.  Was this an upgrade (via Update Manager) or fresh install? Make and Model of Computer?  On the old 12.10 install had you installed any proprietary drivers?

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/285932/33871) helps.