# no sound in the new upgrade! why did this happen?

Tags: indicator-sound

hello I like the new look of your up grade to 13.04
I am trying to get my sound to work
the sounds says that it is a dummy sound
how come the sound card is not working

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: What sound card do you have? (try running `alsamixer`).

Comment: I have faced a similar issue. See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/285932/33871) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-installing `pulseaudio` (more likely if you are using analog audio)
You can also try the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme) (more likely if you are using HDMI audio)