# Unable to get audio through HDMI connection to TV with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I'm having trouble getting audio through my TV which is connected via HDMI.  The item *is* available (**HDMI / DisplayPort 2**) via sound settings, but it doesn't play any sound.  I'm able to get the volume when logged in to Windows on the same setup.

I've tried updating my graphics card drivers through `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers` to **NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331-updates)**

I've done a couple of the things listed here: [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi) (installed `pavucontrol`, did the sound test on the highest voted answer), but they seem to be related to not even seeing the device listed, whereas I have the device listed I just can't get any sound.

When I play through **Speakers - Build-in Audio** it works

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you list what program you are using to control your sound settings. (Not sure this will help, but more information is always nice)

Comment: Just `System Settings > Sound`

Comment: quick question: what kind of graphics card are you using?? Could it be a nvidia optimus card??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just fixed my audio issues spent days updating drivers and it ended up being the most basic setting. Permissions, add yourself to the "audio" group. So pop out to terminal and execute the following command.

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

Hope it works for you as well. It's odd that you are not automatically in that group as sound is an essential service.

Oh, and reboot, just to ensure the permission kicks in.

Comment: Well, that worked... and, agreed, very weird you wouldn't automatically be in the audio group.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Although, you can improve slightly by using `$USER` so that people can just copy/paste the command.

Comment: `sudo adduser $USER audio`

Answer (score 9):

Try these steps:

1. Install `pavucontrol`, if you haven't already, using the command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
   ```
2. Add your username to the groups `audio`, `pulse`, `pulse-access`, `video` and `voice` using the following command:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G audio,pulse,pulse-access,video,voice $USER
   ```

   If the command gives you errors on groups that don't exist, just ignore it.
3. Install the latest ALSA drivers using the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
   ```
4. Reboot and check if audio over HDMI is working.

> Sources:
>
> - http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=153108
> - [No sound through HDMI out, 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285920/no-sound-through-hdmi-out-13-04)

Comment: installing the alsa drivers caused my PC to kernel panic

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem voice is not coming in TV after HDMI cable. I changed my sound setting after that it works perfectly. I changed my default sound setting as shown in image speakers to HDMI.

:

[image: Sound Setting]

Answer (score 1):

Try restart Puseaudio,

after the PulseAudio restart the device now displayed at configuration window.

See command:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

I added $USER to audio group too:

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

From: 
 https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (originally 12.04 -> 16.04) with a GeForce GTX 750 Ti (GM107), and HWE Hardware Enablement Stack, plus nvidia-driver-440 installed (`sudo ubuntu-drivers install`).

`cat /proc/asound/cards` would show `--- no soundcards ---`

I had to reconfigure `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf` to read:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

instead of:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=0 probe_mask=0xfff2
```

`sudo alsa reload` then loads the driver with the correct settings.

Answer (score -1):

This worked on a Dell Inspiron 3647 running Ubuntu Studio 14.04:

1. Opened a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)
2. Typed "alsamixer" at the prompt, then hit enter
3. Hit F6 key, then chose another card from what was listed
4. Tested the sound with a Burning Spear video on Youtube, and had sound

Hope this helps you.

Comment: what for those not having another sound card?

Comment: This is for a system with only 1 sound card: please try the solution verbatim.

Answer (score -2):

I have gone through the same headache [**no sound out with HDMI**] with my ACER Travelmate 8481G laptop with NVIDIA Optimus and Linux.

I tried every solution I could but because i installed a closed solution OpenELEC I was unable to try Bumblebee.

But then it occurred to me;

Bios change GPU from switchable to Discreet and
Disable on-board audio

And this worked perfectly.
NOTE: if you want to have sound come through the laptop speakers you will need to enable the audio when you are done with your HDMI.

Comment: I did it, but didn't work. Also why should it work?

Comment: disabling my NVidia GPU is less acceptable.