# Ubuntu 14.04 Sound on HDMI output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, udev

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have an issue with switching audio output to HDMI when an external monitor (TV) is connected.

Here is my setup:

1. I created "udev rule" 10-hdmi_sound.rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

   `KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/home/basia/test.sh"`

   I checked this rule carefully. It triggers test.sh every time HDMI cable is connected/ disconnected.
2. My `test.sh` is as follows:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   HDMI_STATUS=cat /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/status
   if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ] ; then
     echo 'test' >> /home/user/connected.log
     sudo -u user pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
   else
     echo 'test' >> /home/user/disconnected.log
     sudo -u user pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
   fi
   ```

The script doesn't switch audio output when it's triggered from the udev rule, but works correctly when it's  called manually.
Echo works fine all the time - nevermind how script is called, from udev rule or manually.
It seems there is an issue with "sudo -u user pactl set-card-profile ..." when script is called automatically.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Does the echo work in both cases when you change your script to the above?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0):

Read this post it worked for me...
[Unable to get audio through HDMI connection to TV with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/512621/379182)

$ sudo adduser your_linux_user_name