# No sound through receiver via HDMI

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I am not able to hear sound through my Yamaha receiver on Ubuntu 20.10. It is connected via the HDMI port on my Nvidia 2080TI. On Windows, there's a red HDMI symbol on my receiver indicating that it's connected. This does not appear on Ubuntu.
I am connected to my Samsung CRG90 monitor via the display port from my GPU.

When I go to settings then sound in Ubuntu, it does not give me the option to select HDMI audio.

If I type `pulseaudio -k` in the terminal, `HDMI/DisplayPort 2 - TU102 High Definition Audio Controller` appears in the sound settings. When I select this, I still don't get any sound through my receiver and it still doesn't show the red HDMI symbol on the receiver.

My receiver shows as a display device under `Displays` in my settings, even though I am not running my monitor through it. So, I know that my computer is able to detect my receiver.

I also see TU102 listed in pulse audio volume control.

I've gone through many of the other questions, such as this one: [Unable to get audio through HDMI connection to TV with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512621/unable-to-get-audio-through-hdmi-connection-to-tv-with-ubuntu-14-04)
and have tried the suggestions listed and nothing seems to work.

I don't see a etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf or a /etc/modprobe.d/nvidiahdmi.conf file. Could that be the issue?

I've attached the following images:
[Sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQIoH.png)
[etc/modprobe.d files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma6HX.png)
[pulse audio volume control configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrqM6.png)
[pulse audio volume control output devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tim6I.png)
[alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1gdV.png)
[aplay -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzMbL.png)

Thanks!