# Trouble installing AMD drivers on a new build - using 14.10

Tags: drivers, ati, 15.04, amd-processor

I've just finished building my first PC. I'm also fairly new to Ubuntu.

I'm really struggling to work out how exactly to get the proprietary AMD drivers up and running. I've been trying different methods all day with no pay off

I'be just done new install of 15.04 (as I read that 14.04 can be problematic). My APU is an AMD A10 A7870K.

I'm also planning to put a an Asus Radeon R7 250 in - but it's not a problem if I have to work that out later.

Could anyone give me, or direct me to, an absolutely beginner's level guide to get things working?

Comment: From what I've read it's got all you need right out of the box.

Comment: 14.10 has reached end of life and is no longer supported.

Comment: Okay - have jumped up to 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question has already been answered:

[No sound through HDMI out, 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285920/no-sound-through-hdmi-out-13-04)

A year or two ago a friend and I built a midrange gaming PC on similar hardware. The kernel rollback mentioned in the link took care of not getting audio over the HDMI port and one or two other niggles. What exactly are you seeing that makes you think there's a driver problem?

Comment: It's a problem booting Ubuntu - unless I use nomodeset, I get stuck on the purple screen.